# custom Laravel route not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I created a custom controller action to save the "second level" of my configuration objects, since the initial form saves credentials that are then used to pull available items from a web service.

The second level configuration method is

**ConfigurationController**

```
public function storeTest(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

The route was added to the `web.php` routes file:

**web.php**

```
// configuration routes
Route::resource('configurations', 'ConfigurationController');
Route::put('configurations/test/{$id}', 'ConfigurationController@storeTest')->name('configurations.test_update');
```

The output from `php artisan route:list` shows the route correctly:

```
| PUT | configurations/test/{$id} | configurations.test_update | App\Http\Controllers\ConfigurationController@storeTest | web
```

And finally my form, using the LaravelCollective form package:

```
{!! Form::model($configuration, ['action' => ['ConfigurationController@storeTest', $configuration->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
```

Viewing source on the form page shows that the action looks right:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://myapp.app/configurations/test/20010504142745046252000000" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

But when the form gets submitted, it throws an error saying that `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

Comment: What do you get if you change `'action' => ['ConfigurationController@storeTest', $configuration->id]` to `'route' => ['configurations.test_update', $configuration->id]`?

Comment: It also appears that you're missing your `$id` parameter in your Controller method. Try changing it to: `public function storeTest(Request $request, $id)`

Comment: What if you switch around your configuration in web.php file so the put is just in front of resource as the resource may be catching it before it gets to the put route

Answer (score 0):

The error was really simple. In the route, you don't need to use the dollar sign with the variable:

```
Route::put('configurations/test/{$id}', 'ConfigurationController@storeTest')->name('configurations.test_update');
```

is incorrect. It should just read:

```
Route::put('configurations/test/{id}', 'ConfigurationController@storeTest')->name('configurations.test_update');
```

That solved the issue. Thanks for the help to those who commented.